# Do I need to create an image folder to make a javascript photo library work?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a photo library on my webpage that is interactive and I cannot make it work properly. Do I need to create a library folder for js to connect to?

This is for a medical dispensary's strain library. I am trying to create a photo gallery that allows users to click on a thumbnail of each strain and have it expand to a larger image and description of that strain.

```js
function openLibrary(imgs) {
  var expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
  var imgText = document.getElementById("imgText");
  expandImg.src = imgs.src;
  imgText.innerHTML = imgs.alt;
  expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<div class="row" id="openLibrary">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="../Resources/Images/Big Smooth DN-min.JPG" alt="Big Smooth" onClick="openLibrary('BigSmooth');">
  </div>

  <div id="BigSmooth" class="container" xstyle="display.none" style="display: none;">
    <img src="../Resources/Images/Big Smooth DN.JPG" alt="Big Smooth" style="width: 100%">
    <span onClick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn"> x </span>
  </div>
```

The page displays the thumbnails as it is supposed to, but there is no change when clicked. My JS skills are slim and still learning, this code was found at https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tab_img_gallery.asp

Comment: So is your question if you need a library?

Comment: ***Do I need to create a library folder for js to connect to?*** << No. As long as your file references are valid, they do not have to be in their own folder (although that is a good idea). Do yourself a favor and stay as far away from W3Schools as you can!

Answer (score 0):

Lets take a look to the original JS in https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_tab_img_gallery:

```
function myFunction(imgs) {
  var expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
  var imgText = document.getElementById("imgtext");
  expandImg.src = imgs.src;
  imgText.innerHTML = imgs.alt;
  expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "block";
}
```

The first thing that gets my attention is that we are trying to obtain two DOM elements:

For imgText:

```
 <div id="imgtext"></div>
```

and for expandedImg:

```
<img id="expandedImg" style="width:100%">
```

Now, If we check the html of your question, none of your `img` tags have the proper ids setup:

```
<img src="../Resources/Images/Big Smooth DN-min.JPG" alt="Big Smooth" onClick="openLibrary('BigSmooth');">
```

and

```
<img src="../Resources/Images/Big Smooth DN.JPG" alt="Big Smooth" style="width: 100%">
```

They are both missing the respective id's (expandedImg and imgText).
Therefore, the JS code can't find those `img` tags and doesn't work.

Let me know if my answer makes sense to you.

Comment: @SarahMcFly Glad to be of help. Good luck with your project :)

Answer (score 0):

You pass a string to your function (`openLibrary('BigSmooth')`) and then try to access some attribute `src` on that string, which obviously doesn't exist.

Remove the `.src` and `.alt` after `imgs`, since `imgs` only contains the string `'BigSmooth'` you passed into the function. Just putting `'BigSmooth'` as `src` into the `img` element still won't work though: `src` requires a URL, which you have to assemble, like so:

`expandImg.src = '../Resources/Images/' + imgs + ' DN.JPG';`

(And probably you also meant to write `'Big Smooth'` instead of `'BigSmooth'` when calling your function)

Furthermore, the `id`s you use with `document.getElementById` don't exist. You need to add the `id` attribute to the respective elements, like so:

`<img id="someId" />`